# Save to LocalStorage using Twitter-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage, jqtouch

I have created a website in HTML that has a Settings page, where the user inputs information, clicks Save and the information is saved - as in, if the text fields have text in them then the information remains in that field even if the user leaves the website. I have used jQTouch and jQuery and JavaScript to save the information and it worked fine, but when I re-created the same website with Twitter-BootStrap it stopped working.

The .js files attached to the Settings.html page are;
bootstrap.js; jquery.min.js and (this is my own code) save.js

In the save.js, i saved the text fields using;

```
localStorage.name = $("#name").val();
```

and loaded them using;

```
$("#name").val(localStorage.name);
```

i was wondering if because i don't have jQTouch attached to the HTML anymore that it's stopped working? if so is there a way to change it to work with BootStrap and jQuery?

Any other code you need, just ask. I wasn't sure what you'd need and my GitHub account is experiencing problems. Thanks so much in advance xxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use getItem and setItem to save and load localStorage data this is plain Javascript.

```
localStorage.setItem("name", $("#name").val());

$("#name").val(localStorage.getItem("name"));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it sort of works, when i click save it doesn't immediately vanish but if i leave the page then it disappears :S

Comment: hang on i forgot to say - i have two functions to put this code into, saveSettings and loadSettings, does that change what the code is?

Comment: You could try replacing all localStorage.key = value; to localStorage.setItem(key, value) and localStorage.key to localStorage.getItem(key).

Comment: ok, so it would be `localStorage.setItem('name', ???)` and `localStorage.getItem('name')`? or would there be the # sign in front of any of them?

Comment: localStorage.setItem(key, value) and localStorage.getItem(key);

This: $("#name").val() has nothing to do with it, it's jQuery and get the value of an element with ID name.

That means it would be localStorage.setItem('theKeyOfYourDataItem', 'theValueOfYourDataItem');

Comment: ok i get it, but i don't know what the value of the item is, the user inputs the value. or am i misunderstanding you? sorry if this sounds stupid or slow i just want to be completely sure i understand you x

Comment: Actually you DO know what the value is it's: $("#name").val() you can use that as a value. The exact value will be returned by Javascript.

Comment: oh! sorry i misunderstood what you were saying earlier :S sorry